# multiple mat-select start with all checked?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, material-design

I have a dinamicly mat-select in an Angular4 app. What I need is: when I fill the mat-select options, I need to set all the options as checked. I tried many thins but no one worked. Please help.

This is what I got:

ts:

```
options = {
    0: 'op1',
    1: 'op2',
    2: 'op3',
    3: 'op4'
  };
```

but the `options` variable can change. Sometimes the length can be 5, sometimes can be 16, sometimes 0, that is dinamic.

Then, in my HTML i got this:

```
<mat-select multiple placeholder="Options" required="true" [(ngModel)]="selected-options">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let op of options" [value]="op">{{ op }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Look the `multiple` in the mat-select tag.

THIS WORKS! but that just set the options in the select and the value is unchecked.

So... how can I set all the items checked?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preselecting multiple values for mat-select - Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491710/preselecting-multiple-values-for-mat-select-angular-6)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<mat-select multiple placeholder="Options" required="true" [formControl]="selectedOptions">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let op of options" [value]="op">{{ op }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**In your TS:**

```
options: string[] = {'op1','op2','op3','op4'};
selectedOptions = new FormControl(this.options);
```

Comment: Thanks same problem i to faced Now Working fine , But can you explain how did it worked i am trying to figure out but i am unable ,plz help me to understand how it worked

Answer (score 0):

Just insert to `selected-options` the value you want to be selected, for example:

```
selected-options = ['op1', 'op2', 'op3', 'op4']
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-all)