# Preselecting multiple values for mat-select - Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to preselect multiple options in a mat-select. So far I'm not able to achieve this.

Here is the HTML file:

```
<mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="form">
   <mat-form-field>
     <mat-select placeholder="participants" formControlName="participants"  multiple>
         <mat-option *ngFor="let participant of participants" [value]="participant">{{participant}}</mat-option>
     </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

Here is the controller:

```
export class EventViewModalComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  calendarEvent: CalendarEvent;
  participants = [];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private participantService: ParticipantService,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) event: CalendarEvent) 
    { 
    this.form = fb.group({
      title: [event.title, Validators.required],
      location: [event.meta.location, Validators.required],
      description: [event.meta.description, Validators.required],
      start: [event.start, Validators.required],
      end: [event.end, Validators.required],
      participants: [this.participants, Validators.required]
    });
    this.calendarEvent = event;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.participantService.getAll().subscribe(data =>{
      for(let i = 0; i < data['length']; i++){
        this.participants.push(data[i]['name']);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

This currently selects all the values per default. Here's a screenshot of how it looks currently:
[image]

**What I'm trying to achieve is having only Cindy and Jim preselected like this:**

[image]

How can I achieve this? I've read through several SO questions and wasn't successful. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe that the easiest way is to use `[(ngModel)]` directive (or a one-way binding, I'll cover it shortly later) to manipulate the value of `mat-select`: you can bind a variable, which contains elements you want to preselect, something like this:

```
<mat-select placeholder="participants" formControlName="participants" multiple [(ngModel)]="selection">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let participant of participants" [value]="participant">{{participant}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

And then you can just filter your initial array of items and get only those, which you want to select by default (it should be stored in `selection` class property in provided case).

I have created a [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgeoyn?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts) to demonstrate, that it's possible. In this example, I filter items at even indexes, and finally we get *"1'st, 3'rd, 5'th, ..."* items selected.

Notice, that you can split `[(ngModel)]` into 2 separate directives if you want to use only a one-way binding: `[ngModel]` or `(ngModelChange)`. For more info, take a look at [angular template syntax guide](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inside-ngmodel).

Answer (score 25):

With Angular6+ there is a deprecation warning when you have both a formControl and [(ngModel)]

> It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as
> formControl.
> Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with
> reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed
> in Angular v7.

**Option 1 using [ngModel] without FormControl**

As the first answer suggests, split [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) like this.

```
<mat-select 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedFoods" 
  (ngModelChange)="selectedFoods" name="selectedFoods" 
  placeholder="Favorite food" multiple>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let food of allfoods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

And for the ts.

```
  allfoods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'},
    {value: 'pasta-3', viewValue: 'Pasta'}
  ];
  selectedFoods = [
     'steak-0', 'pasta-3'
  ];
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-with-ngmodel?embed=1&file=app/select-overview-example.ts

**Option 2 using [formControl] without [ngModel]**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [formControl]="foodForm" placeholder="Favorite food" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of allfoods" [value]="food.value">
            {{food.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In this case, the selection is initialised in the FormControl's constructor.

```
 allfoods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'},
    {value: 'pasta-3', viewValue: 'Pasta'}
    ];
 myselectedFoods = ['pasta-3', 'steak-0'];
 foodForm: FormControl = new FormControl(this.myselectedFoods);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-multi-with-formcontrol